# Need help for writing regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am weak in writing regular expressions so I'm going to need some help on the one. I need a regular expression that can validate that a string is an set of alphabets (the alphabets must be unique) delimited by comma.

Only one character and after that a comma

Examples:

```
A,E,R
R,A
E,R
```

Thanks

Comment: so there's no comma after the last char or there can be a comma? By character you mean any unicode or letter?

Comment: yes no comma after last letter, Character i mean only three upper case alphabets A,E and R

Comment: `set of alphabet` So are the alphabets required to be unique?

Comment: yes alphabets must be unique only comma can appear 0 or above times, rest of alphabets are 0 or 1,

Comment: @user3580890 so you mean ```A,A``` is invalid?

Comment: multiple ways man. one simple way ^[A-Z,]*$

Comment: @user3580890 Did yo want to allow `R,A,R`?

Comment: No, this is also in valid

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk, thanks for your help i am using the below site to test the regular expr http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: If your requirement is that the letters must be unique, this is beyond the capability of regexes in the general case (since there are only three letters, you could hack one up, but it's not worth it).  Your best approach is to shift to another method, using either `split` or a loop with `find` to find the letters, then use a `Set` such as a `HashSet` to keep track of which letters you see and check for uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a repeated group to validate it's a comma separated string.

```
^[AER](?:,[AER])*$
```

To not have unique characters, you would do something like:

```
^([AER])(?:,(?!\1)([AER])(?!.*\2))*$
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, a valid string will be a series (possibly zero long) of two-character patterns, where each pattern is a letter followed by a comma; finally followed at the end by one letter.

Thus:

```
"^([A-Za-z],)*[A-Za-z]$"
```

**EDIT:** Since you've clarified that the letters have to be A, E, or R:

```
"^([AER],)*[AER]$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this `"^([AER],)*[AER]$"`

@Edit: regarding the uniqueness, if you can drop the "last character cannot be a comma" requirement (which can be checked before the regex anyway in constant time) then this should work:

`"^(?:([AER],?)(?!.*\\1))*$"`

This will match `A,E,R,` hence you need that check before performing the regex. I do not take responsibility for the performance but since it's only 3 letters anyway...

The above is a java regex obviously, if you want a "pure one" `^(?:([AER],?)(?!.*\1))*$`

@Edit2: sorry, missed one thing: this actually requires that check and then you need to add a comma at the end since otherwise it will also match `A,E,E`. Kind of limited I know.

Comment: This is equivalent to `^[AER](,[AER])*$`, which is actually better, because it is won't need to back up one character to match.

Comment: good point, I wasn't really concerned with performance after reading that it can only have 3 letters but definitely worth noting should the alphabet be bigger.

Comment: @Quincunx posting those as answers would be better imho, people might not read the comment section and I don't want to take credit for someone's answers so I won't edit :-)

Comment: @Quincunx your regex allows `A,A`

Answer (score 1):

#### Note: I'm going to answer the original question. That is, I don't care if the elements repeat.

We've had several suggestions for this regex:

```
^([AER],)*[AER]$
```

Which does indeed work. However, to match a String, it first has to back up one character because it will find that there is no `,` at the end. So we switch it for this to increase performance:

```
^[AER](,[AER])*$
```

Notice that this will match a correct String the very first time it attempts to. But also note that we don't need to worry about the `(      )*` backing up at all; it will either match the first time, or it won't match the String at all. So we can further improve performance by using a possessive quantifier:

```
^[AER](,[AER])*+$
```

This will take the whole String and attempt to match it. If it fails, then it stops, saving time by not doing useless backing up.

---

If I were trying to ensure the String had no repeated elements, I would not use regex; it just complicates things. You end up with less-readable code (sadly, most people don't understand regex) and, oftentimes, slower code. So I would build my own validator:

```
public static boolean isCommaDelimitedSet(String toValidate, HashSet<Character> toMatch) {
    for (int index = 0; index < toValidate.length(); index++) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            if (!toMatch.contains(toValidate.charAt(index))) return false;
        } else {
            if (toValidate.charAt(index) != ',') return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This assumes that you want to be able to pass in a set of characters that are allowed. If you don't want that and have explicit chars you want to match, change the contents of the `if (index % 2 == 0)` block to:

```
char c = toValidate.charAt(index);
if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'R' || /* and so on */ ) return false;
```

Comment: @nhahtdh I prefer to say that I don't understand poor English that well. I understood that "set" to mean that we are choosing each character from a set of characters. Not that they have to be unique.

Comment: @nhahtdh people aren't always very precise and don't always associate set with uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

My own ugly but extensible solution, which will disallow leading and trailing commas, and checks that the characters are unique.

It uses forward-declared backreference: note how the second capturing group is behind the reference made to it `(?!.*\2)`. On the first repetition, since the second capturing group hasn't captured anything, Java treats any attempt to reference text match by second capturing group as failure.

```
^([AER])(?!.*\1)(?:,(?!.*\2)([AER]))*+$
```

[**Demo on regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/pW0kN0/1) (PCRE flavor has the same behavior for this case)

[**Demo on RegexPlanet**](http://fiddle.re/c297t)

Test cases:

```
A,E,R
A,R,E
E,R,A
A
R,E
R
E

A,
A,R,
A,A,R
E,A,E
A,E,E
X,R,E
R,A,E,
,A
AA,R,E
```